# Why does ROS_HOSTNAME overwrite (parts of) ROS_MASTER_URI?

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, ros-hostname

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this example:

```
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://my_pc_name:11311
$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.10.125
$ roscore
... logging to /home/marcus/.ros/log/666dd760-de3b-11e2-a641-f46d04929542/roslaunch-pirate-nest-2653.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.10.125:40223/
ros_comm version 1.9.46


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2679]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.10.125:11311/

setting /run_id to 666dd760-de3b-11e2-a641-f46d04929542
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2718]
started core service [/rosout]
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.10.125:11311
$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=my_pc_name
$ roscore
... logging to /home/marcus/.ros/log/75dd2e8a-de3b-11e2-a4fa-f46d04929542/roslaunch-pirate-nest-2820.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://my_pc_name:52467/
ros_comm version 1.9.46


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2834]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://my_pc_name:11311/

setting /run_id to 75dd2e8a-de3b-11e2-a4fa-f46d04929542
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2852]
started core service [/rosout]
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Is this supposed to happen?

It's not a huge problem, but took me a while to figure it out ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65967/why-does-ros_hostname-overwrite-(parts-of)-ros_master_uri?/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not overriding the ROS_MASTER_URI, it is telling you what it thinks your ROS_MASTER_URI should be, as that is where the master is listening. The master respects ROS_HOSTNAME when launching and does not follow the ROS_MASTER_URI.

It does try to sanity check ROS_MASTER_URI such as verifying the port number and that it can reach itself at the known address.

```
$ roscore -p 11111
... logging to /home/tfoote/.ros/log/f523818c-0396-11e3-9904-902b34db2f33/roslaunch-BigFoote-29198.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://BigFoote:40065/
ros_comm version 1.9.47


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI port [11311] does not match this roscore [11111]
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [29212]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://BigFoote:11111/
...
```

With an invalid hostname

```
$ ROS_HOSTNAME=invalid roscore -p 11111
... logging to /home/tfoote/.ros/log/63b53302-0397-11e3-9aa5-902b34db2f33/roslaunch-BigFoote-29441.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Unable to contact my own server at [http://invalid:59015/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot ping itself.  Please check
for errors by running:

    ping invalid

For more tips, please see

    http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup
```

And differently set ROS_MASTER_URI hostname:

```
$ ROS_MASTER_URI=http://invalid:11111 roscore -p 11111
... logging to /home/tfoote/.ros/log/966bed7c-0397-11e3-90cd-902b34db2f33/roslaunch-BigFoote-29549.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://BigFoote:36475/
ros_comm version 1.9.47


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://invalid:11111] host is not set to this machine
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [29564]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://BigFoote:11111/
...
```

If there's a difference between what's in your bashrc and what it prints it is a warning sign that you should double check that they resolve to the same machine on all systems.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-08-12**:
I see. Thanks for the insight!